# Creating DDL scripts from Hibernate Annotation Classes Using ANT

Tags: sql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, orm, ant

I’m trying to **generate SQL DDL  from my Hibernate annotation beans using ANT**, according to hibernate tools document I have created the following Ant script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="yourmarketnet" default="all" basedir=".">
<property name="build.dir" value="C:/Users/naim/Documents/NetBeansProjects/yourmarketnet/build" />
<target name="ddl_generation">
<!-- paths to required jars  -->
<path location="web/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-annotations.jar" />
<path location="web/WEB-INF/lib/ejb3-persistence.jar" />
<path location="web/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-entitymanager.jar" />
<path location="web/WEB-INF/lib/javaassist.jar" />
<path location="web/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-tools.jar"/>
<path location="web/WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-entitymanager.jar" />
<path location="web/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-archive-browsing.jar" />
<path location="web/WEB-INF/lib/javaassist.jar" />

<taskdef name="hibernatetool" classname="org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask">
    </taskdef>
    <classpath>
    <!-- path of annotation beans -->
<path location="${build.dir}/web/WEB-INF/classes/com/yourmarketnet/beans" />
</classpath>
<!-- output destination -->
<hibernatetool destdir="${build.dir}">
<!-- were the annotation beans files are located-->
<!-- list exporters here -->
<hbm2ddl
export="false"
update="false"
drop="true"
create="true"
outputfilename="myApps.ddl"
delimiter=";"
format="false"
haltonerror="true"/>
</hibernatetool>
</target>
</project>
```

However Im getting the following error:

taskdef class org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask cannot be found
 using the classloader AntClassLoader[]

I have checked my /lib & folder and classpath hibernate-tools is present.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating DDL scripts from JPA/Hibernate Annotation Classes Using ANT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858844/creating-ddl-scripts-from-jpa-hibernate-annotation-classes-using-ant)

Comment: Please don't post exactly the same question twice...  The classpath is not declared inside the taskdef XML tags. This would explain why it cannot pick up the hibernate jars.

Answer (score 1):

In my ant scripts, I usually define a property named lib.dir with the absolute path to my lib folder, and use the  tag to load all my jars, as relative paths for one reason or another have always been a problem for me. Might be worth a shot for you as well.

```
<property name="lib.dir" value="C:\path\to\project\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib"/>
<property name="jdk.home" value="C:\path\to\jdk" />
<path id="project.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <pathelement location="${jdk.home}/jre/javaws/javaws.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${jdk.home}/jre/lib/charsets.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${jdk.home}/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${jdk.home}/jre/lib/ext/ldapsec.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${jdk.home}/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${jdk.home}/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${jdk.home}/jre/lib/im/indicim.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${jdk.home}/jre/lib/im/thaiim.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${jdk.home}/jre/lib/jce.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${jdk.home}/jre/lib/jsse.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${jdk.home}/jre/lib/plugin.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${jdk.home}/jre/lib/rt.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${jdk.home}/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${jdk.home}/lib/dt.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${jdk.home}/lib/htmlconverter.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${jdk.home}/lib/tools.jar"/>
</path>
...
// Rest of your build file
...
```